# ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
drop database if exists foodtruck_DB;
create database if not exists foodtruck_DB;
use foodtruck_DB;

create table if not exists Customer (
phone char(10),
email varchar(50),
pnum_FK Varchar(10),
constraint customer_PK primary key (email,pnum_fk) );

INSERT INTO Customer(pnum_FK, email, phone) VALUES
("PID101", "Ben@gmail.com","2155552256"),
("PID102","Leonard@gmail.com","2155515975"),
("PID103","Marcus@gmail.com","2675589787"),
("PID104","Phillip@gmail.com","2674847485"),
("PID105","Hawk@gmail.com","2154567895");

create table if not exists customer_order (
order_num varchar(10),
otype  char(10),
email_FK varchar(50),
pnum char(10),
constraint customer_order_PK primary key (order_num),
constraint customer_order_FK foreign key (email_FK)
references Customer(email) );

INSERT INTO Customer_order(order_num,otype,pnum,email_FK) VALUES
("Order#919","Delivery","PID209","Ben@gmail.com"),
("Order#920","Delivery","PID210","Leonard@gmail.com"),
("Order#921","Delivery","PID211","Marcus@gmail.com"),
("Order#922","Delivery","PID212","clmxr66@gail.com");


create table if not exists Order_item(
autogen int auto_increment,
order_num_FK varchar(10),
item_num char(10),
constraint order_item_PK primary key(autogen),
constraint order_item_FK foreign key (order_num_FK)
references customer_order(order_num) );

INSERT INTO Order_item(item_num,order_num_FK) VALUES 
("Invo#10","2"),
("Invo#11","3"),
("Invo#12","5"),
("Invo#13","2"),
("Invo#14","1");

create table if not exists point_of_sale (
amount double,
paytype varchar(10),
CusID varchar(25),
itemID char(25),
reciptID varchar(25),
constraint point_of_sale_PK primary key (reciptID) );

INSERT INTO point_of_sale(CusID,itemID,reciptID,paytype,amount) VALUES
('s208c','RID#','222','Credit','10.47'),
('mwtqg','RID#','223','Cash','15.55'),
('c1g4n','RID#','224','Credit','7.5'),
('3wns6','RID#','225','Credit','20.15'),
('bph7o','RID#','226','Cash','30.1');

create table if not exists product(
pro_num varchar(5),
pro_name varchar(50),
category varchar(50),
reorder_lvl varchar(10),
itemID_FK varchar(10),
price double,
constraint product_pK primary key (pro_num),
constraint product_FK foreign key (itemID_FK) references point_of_sale(itemID));

insert into product(pro_num,pro_name,category,reorder_lvl,itemID_FK,price) values
('PR0#','299','pickles','Food','high','I44','1'),
('PR0#','300','hot sauce','Sauce','low','I45','1.5'),
('PR0#','301','olives','food','low','I46',  '0.5'),
('PR0#','302','mustard','Sauce','high','I47','0.5'),
('PR0#','303','tomatoes','food','high', 'I48','1');

create table if not exists vendor (
ven_name varchar(25),
venID varchar(10),
constraint vendor_PK primary key (venID) );
```

Answer (score 1):

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
> central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
> back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
> table.
>
> It will reject any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create
> a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching
> candidate key value in the parent table.

1. In the customer_order table you are trying to insert `("Order#922","Delivery","PID212","clmxr66@gail.com");` with  the email constraint and the value `clmxr66@gail.com` doesn't exist on Customer table.
2. In the following insert there isn't any `order_num_FK` value which exists on  order_num column on customer_order table

   `INSERT INTO Order_item(item_num,order_num_FK) VALUES  ("Invo#10","2"), ("Invo#11","3"), ("Invo#12","5"), ("Invo#13","2"), ("Invo#14","1");`
3. itemID in the point_of_sale table should be indexed and with same datatype and length with itemID_FK column on product table for the following constraint to work

   `constraint product_FK foreign key (itemID_FK) references point_of_sale(itemID));`
4. You haven't included any of the values of itemID_FK aren't included on the itemID column of the point_of_sale table which makes the following constraint fails.

`constraint product_FK foreign key (itemID_FK) references point_of_sale(itemID)`

*Note*, I made some changes/fixes on [this working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8MKelDPw)

[Must read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)